# Binding ObservableCollection in viewmodel to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I'm very new to MVVM and bindings and I'm trying to learn to work with it.
I run into the problem of binding my viewmodel to the view in particular binding an observable collection to a listbox.

this is what my viewmodel looks like:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    using Model; 

public class NetworkViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _networkList1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> NetworkList1 //Binds with the listbox
    {
        get { return _networkList1; }
        set { _networkList1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged("_networkList1"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public NetworkViewModel() 
    {
        _networkList1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){FirstName="John", LastName="Doe"},
            new Person(){FirstName="Andy" , LastName="Boo"}
        };
   }
}
```

in the view I have

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Networking : Window
    {

        public Networking()
       {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new NetworkViewModel();

            lb1.ItemsSource = _networkList1;
        }
     }
}
```

and in the XAML I have

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkList1}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock >
                         <Run Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                         <Run Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: If you are new to MVVM, I would highly suggest that you look at using a MVVM Framework. One example (the one I use) is Caliburn.Micro (http://caliburnmicro.com). MVVM frameworks make things super easy, such as automatically binding to a public property on your view model simply by setting the `x:Name` of a control in your view to match the property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Gaurav answer, if `_networkList1` is a private field in your `NetworkViewModel` class, how is it possible to get access to it in `Networking` window? I mean what's the meaning of the following line?

```
lb1.ItemsSource = _networkList1;
```

when you define a **Property** (`NetworkList1`), you have to **use** it in order to get advantages of its features (e.g. to get `RaisePropertyChanged` working). Otherwise what's the point, you could have just defined a field (`_networklist1`). So changing

```
_networkList1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
```

to

```
NetworkList1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
```

results in actually setting `NetworkList1` and therefore `RaisePropertyChanged("NetworkList1")` to be fired. (however if you want to just show data in a your listbox this is unnecessary)

and if i'm getting it right, changing this:

```
public partial class Networking : Window
{

    public Networking()
   {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new NetworkViewModel();

        lb1.ItemsSource = _networkList1;
    }
 }
```

to

```
    public partial class Networking : Window
    {

        public NetworkViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }
        public Networking()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyViewModel = new NetworkViewModel();

            this.DataContext = MyViewModel;

        }
    }
```

should get your binding to work.

*Note that when you set `DataContext` to `NetworkViewModel`, then the binding in

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkList1}">
```

works, because `NetworkList1` is a Property of `NetworkViewModel`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might have a typo in your view model.

```
RaisePropertyChanged("_networkList1");
```

You want to raise the property changed notification for the public property not the private variable.

```
RaisePropertyChanged("NetworkList1");
```

This might be preventing your view from updating properly.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my problem, I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I still don't get any data in the listbox.

Comment: I just noticed that you are also setting the ItemSource property both in code and in XAML. in MVVM, you shouldn't have to set any other properties from code except for DataContext. Some frameworks even do that in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `RaisePropertyChanged()` method on `ObservableCollection<T>`, for god's sake. This is a common mistake in a majority of cases (however, there are cases, where you need to reset `ObservableCollection<T>` using `new` keyword, but they are kinda rare).
This is a special type of collection which notifies UI internally about all the changes of its content (like add, remove etc.). What you need is to set the collection using `new` keyword once in a lifetime of your ViewModel, and then manipulate your items via `Add(T item)`, `Remove(T item)`, `Clear()` methods etc.
and UI will get notified about it and updated automatically.